# Concatenate words based on groups

Tags: r

I have a data set as below -

```
cust  cards
  a  ICICI
  a   HDFC
  a    PNB
  b  ICICI 
  b    PNB
  b   AMEX
  c    RCB
  c   AMEX
  d    PNB
```

I want one record for each customer so my output should be like

```
Cust new_cards
a     ICICI,HDFC,PNB
b     ICICI,PNB,AMEX
```

I am using following command -

```
x = group_by(data,cust)%>% mutate(new_cards=cat(cards,sep=","))
```

And getting error. Please let me know how can I get the desired output and if I can do this with function as well?

Comment: `with(data, tapply(cards, cust, toString))`

Comment: There is this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514988/concatenate-strings-by-group-with-dplyr

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation from the previous answer using `toString`:

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(cust) %>%
    summarise(new_cards = toString(cards));
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#  cust  new_cards
#  <fct> <chr>
#1 a     ICICI, HDFC, PNB
#2 b     ICICI, PNB, AMEX
#3 c     RCB, AMEX
#4 d     PNB
```

Comment: Nice. According to the documentation, the specific purpose of `toString` is to produce a concise description of R objects so its use might be misleading.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `toString` actually just does a `paste(x, collapse = ", ")`, see `getAnywhere(toString.default)`. So your solution is cleaner;-)

Comment: Well (a) that’s only the default implementation and (b) it also limits the maximum width (if given).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I actually never noticed the option to limit its `width`. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is to use `summarize`, with `paste`:

```
data %>%
    group_by(cust) %>%
    summarize(new_cards = paste(cards, collapse = ', '))
```

On your example data, this results in

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  cust  new_cards
  <fct> <chr>
1 a     ICICI, HDFC, PNB
2 b     ICICI, PNB, AMEX
3 c     RCB, AMEX
4 d     PNB
```

The `cat` function misled you since it’s badly named: it doesn’t concatenate strings, it prints strings (to the terminal or a file).