# Paste strings in different columns using R

Tags: r

My question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514988/concatenate-strings-by-group-with-dplyr) but in my case, I want the values to be in different columns instead of being concatenated to one.

For example, using the following toy dataframe,

Input:

```
  Patient    Value
    1         'A' 

    1         'B'

    1         'C' 

    1         'D' 

    2         'B' 

    2        

    2         'E'

    and so on.....
```

I would like to create a new one where all the measurements are grouped per patient, i.e. 
Output:

```
  Patient    Value1    Value 2  Value 3  Value  
    1         'A'        'B'      'C'     'D'
    2         'B'                 'E'
```

Please note the absence of a value is still taken into account. How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could `spread` the data into 'wide' format after creating a sequence by 'Patient'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(Patient) %>% 
     mutate(nm = str_c("Value", row_number())) %>%
     spread(nm, Value, fill = "")
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Patient [2]
#  Patient Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
#    <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1       1 A      B      C      D     
#2       2 B      ""     E      ""
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Patient = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Value = c("A", 
 "B", "C", "D", "B", NA, "E")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It works like a charm. The only problem is that the newly created spread columns are re-arranged alphabetically or something. E.g Column Value10 will be after column Value1. Can we avoid that?

Comment: @laza yes, after the mutate step, convert the 'nm' to `factor` with `levels` specified `%>% mutate(nm = factor(nm, levels = unique(nm)))  %>% spread(nm, Value, fill = "")`