# Multiple same rows to one row, but rows at different amount

Tags: r, text, nlp

I have data like this:

| id | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bus |
| 1 | arrive |
| 1 | stop |
| 1 | time |
| 1 | beard |
| 1 | bearded |
| 1 | sits |
| 2 | whilst |
| 2 | argue |
| 2 | seat |
| 2 | time |
| 2 | police |
| 3 | officer |
| 3 | walks |
| 3 | intervenes |

I want to convert it to a dataset like:

| id | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | arrive bus stop time beard bearded sits |
| 2 | whilst begin argue seat time |
| 3 | officer walks intervenes |

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're happy to use the tidyverse packages, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38515351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add some detail to my comment:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,        ~word,
   1L,     "arrive",
   1L,        "bus",
   1L,       "stop",
   1L,       "time",
   1L,      "beard",
   1L,    "bearded",
   1L,       "sits",
   2L,     "whilst",
   2L,      "begin",
   2L,      "argue",
   2L,       "seat",
   2L,       "time",
   2L,     "police",
   3L,    "officer",
   3L,      "walks",
   3L, "intervenes"
  )

data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(word = paste0(word, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% # Take the first line from each group
  ungroup()
```

or better (so you don't need the slice):

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(word = paste0(word, collapse = " "))
```