# Combining multiple rows into one single row in Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

Suppose I have a dataframe, which looks like this.

|  Category  |  Text                  |

| :--------: | :--------------------: |

| First      | I am Groot.            |

| First      | We are Groot.          |

| Second     | The Dark Knight Rises. |

| Second     | I am Batman.           |

But we want to combine rows in column Text, which happens to have same value in category column, into one row and make it look like this.

| Category | Text                                 |

| -------- | ------------------------------------ |

| First    | I am Groot. We are Groot.            |

| Second   | The Dark Knight Rises. I am Batman.  |

How do I do that?

Comment: Would answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514988/concatenate-strings-by-group-with-dplyr) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt0 <- data.table(
  Category = c(rep("First", 2), rep("Second", 2)),
  Text = c("I am Groot.", "We are Groot.", "The Dark Knight Rises.", "I am Batman.")
)
dt <- dt0[, .(Text = paste0(Text, collapse = " ")), by = .(Category)]
dt
```

Explanation: `paste0` takes the column `Text` (which, in `data.table` syntax is evaluated to `dt$Text`) and collapses it to a single value. This calculation is performed for each unique value in `Category`, indicated by `by = .(Category)`.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your response, I want to do reverse actually, i.e. if my dataframe looks like dt alsready and I want to make it look like dt0, what do I do.

Comment: First, you need to define where exactly to split your Text. After each dot?

Comment: I want to compile not separate.

Comment: But that is exactly what the solution I posted above does. ```dt``` contains 2 rows whereas the original data.table ```dt0``` contains 4.

Comment: My bad, it does